# LINQ where list within a list contains a value

Tags: c#, linq

Good morning! I'm pretty new to using LINQ and I've tried all the combinations I can think of and have not been successful. I have a Calendar object and within that object, a list of CalendarDays. What I'm trying to do is retrieve a specific date or date range. Obviously, I want the Calendar values as well as the element of the CalendarDay list. I've tried a number of different combinations, but they tell me I can't convert my CalendarDay to type bool. Here's an example I tried, but I only get the CalendarDay, not the Calendar. Is it not possible to get both values?

```
        var row = calendar.SelectMany(c => c.Days)
                            .Where(d => d.Date == request.Date);
```

Here's my Calendar class:

```
  public class Calendar : ICalendar<string>
    {
        private List<CalendarDay> _calendarDays;

        public Calendar()
        {
            _calendarDays = new List<CalendarDay>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public List<CalendarDay> Days { get => _calendarDays; }

        public void AddCalendarDay(int quarter, string season, int period, int weekOfPeriod, int weekOfYear, int dayOfYear, string date)
        {
            var existingDay = _calendarDays.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Date == date);

            if (existingDay == null)
            {
                _calendarDays.Add(new CalendarDay
                {
                    Quarter = quarter,
                    Season = season,
                    Period = period,
                    WeekOfPeriod = weekOfPeriod,
                    WeekOfYear = weekOfYear,
                    DayOfYear = dayOfYear,
                    Date = date
                });
            }
            else
            {
                existingDay.Quarter = quarter;
                existingDay.Season = season;
                existingDay.Period = period;
                existingDay.WeekOfPeriod = weekOfPeriod;
                existingDay.WeekOfYear = weekOfYear;
                existingDay.DayOfYear = dayOfYear;
                existingDay.Date = date;
            }
        }
    }
```

I forgot to mention that this is a GET method for an API and this retrieval is in the GetByDate handler. As you can see below, the results of the GetItemsAsync is being populated to a List. Right after that is where I want to extract the single date and pass it to the mapper. Hope this helps clarify what I'm looking for!

```
public async Task<CalendarDto> HandleAsync(GetCalendarByDateQuery request)
{
    var spec = new CalendarByYearSpecification(request.Year);
    var result = await _masterRepository.GetItemsAsync(spec);
    
    var calendar = result.Results.ToList();

    // retrieval of the specific date goes here

    var dto = _mapper.Map<Calendar, CalendarDto>(calendar.FirstOrDefault());
    return dto;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is _calendar_ a list or some other enumerable type?

Comment: Hi Steve. Calendar is not a list. It's just a class with year level information

Comment: You code only has one level so you must use Select instead of SelectMany.

Comment: So you shouldn't be able to use  an IEnumerable extension like where on it. Could you show how Calendar is defined?

Comment: jdweng - Weird. When I change the SelectMany to Select it then says the "List<CalendarDay> doesn't contain a definition for Date", which it does find with SelectMany.

Comment: @ChrisP if `calendar` is not a collection (meaning something that implements `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`), you won't be able to use LINQ methods on it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

Comment: We can't see your code if you don't post it here. What we see is code where `calendar` is not an IEnumerable and so `Select()` and `SelectMany()` are not availabe and so your code cannot work. Pls. update your code and then explain what's not working including infos like the property name (there is nothing like "Calendar values", "CalendarDay list" and other thinks you mentioned in your description...

Comment: Given your comment "When I change the SelectMany to Select it then says the "List<CalendarDay> doesn't contain a definition for Date" `calendar` can't be an instance of `Calendar` - what's the type of `calendar`?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm also fairly new to C# so I'm still trying to come up to speed on the terminology, after 30+ years as an IBM iSeries developer. Who says you can't teach an old dog new tricks?! Lol.  I've added some additional code to the post. This is part of an API.

Comment: @ChrisP: When you say you want to return _both_ the `Calendar` _abd_ `CalendarDay`s, what are you expecting? It sounds like you want to return a _new_ `Calendar` instance with the same values as the original, _except_ you want its `Days` property filtered by your LINQ query. Is that right?

Comment: As for the above confusion, given your new code it seems as though one of the conceptual problems is your variable name. You return `result.Results.ToList()` to a variable named `calendar`—but that’s not an instance of your `Calendar` class, as the name suggests, but likely a _list_ of `Calendar` classes, in which case your `SelectMany()` choice makes more sense.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Yes, that's right. The Calendar object contains year level info, so I want that as well as the single day from CalendarDay based on the requested date.

Comment: Jeremy, my SelectMany example above is only returning CalendarDay, not Calendar with the single CalendarDay entry. Is there a way to return both?

Comment: Which LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best course of action is to create a new method inside the Calendar class that filters your dates and return a new Calendar object with just the dates selected

```
public class Calendar : ICalendar<string>
{
    private List<CalendarDay> _calendarDays;

    public Calendar()
    {
        _calendarDays = new List<CalendarDay>();
    }

    public Calendar FilterByDate(CalendarDay requestedDate)
    {
         Calendar result = new Calendar();

         // These lines could be a lot more complex if you have many 
         // properties to duplicate. As it stands now this will suffice, 
         // but in more complex cases you could look at some form of 
         // serialization and deserialization 
         result.Id = this.Id;
         result.Year = this.Year;
         result.Days = this.Days.Where(x => x.Date == requestedDate.Date).ToList();
         return result;
    }
```

Now you need to make the Days property accessible from the internal code of the Calendar class to be able to set it with the results of the Where

```
 public List<CalendarDay> Days { get => _calendarDays; internal set {_calendarDays = value;}}
```

This will allow you to call the method in this way

```
 Calendar filtered = currentCalendar.FilterByDate(aCalendarDayInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like already have your calendar object, so the values are already available to you. Then if you wanted to get a specific calendar day then you can get that using `FirstOrDefault` (assuming you want it to return `null` if it doesn't exist):

```
var calendarDay = calendar.Days.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Date == request.Date);
```

If you wanted a date range then you can use a `Where` method.

```
var calendarDays = calendar.Days.Where(d => d.Date > request.StartDate && d.Date < request.EndDate).ToList();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with .Select() and anonymous types. First, you run your select statement on your calendar collection, and get an anonymous type containing a reference to the calendar as well as a collection of days matching your filter. Then you select only the objects that have a Days.Count higher than zero:

```
var rows = calendar.Select(c => new { Calendar = c, 
                                      Days = c.Days.Where(d => d.Date == request.Date).ToList() })
                   .Where(cd => cd.Days.Count() > 0)
                   .ToList();

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var cal = row.Calendar;
    foreach (var day in row.Days)
    {
        var dayDate = day.Date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the modified version of your code, which contains a set of fix to **make it work**:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

interface ICalendar<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
  
}

public class CalendarDay
{
    public int Quarter {get;set;}
    public string Season {get;set;}
    public int Period {get;set;}
    public int WeekOfPeriod {get;set;}
    public int WeekOfYear {get;set;}
    public int DayOfYear {get;set;}
    public string Date {get;set;}
}

public class Calendar : ICalendar<CalendarDay>
{
    private List<CalendarDay> _calendarDays;

    public Calendar()
    {
        _calendarDays = new List<CalendarDay>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public List<CalendarDay> Days { get => _calendarDays; }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
       return _calendarDays.Select(x => x).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<CalendarDay> GetEnumerator()
    {
       return _calendarDays.Select(x => x).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void AddCalendarDay(int quarter, string season, int period, int weekOfPeriod, int weekOfYear, int dayOfYear, string date)
    {
        var existingDay = _calendarDays.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Date == date);

        if (existingDay == null)
        {
            _calendarDays.Add(new CalendarDay
            {
                Quarter = quarter,
                Season = season,
                Period = period,
                WeekOfPeriod = weekOfPeriod,
                WeekOfYear = weekOfYear,
                DayOfYear = dayOfYear,
                Date = date
            });
        }
        else
        {
            existingDay.Quarter = quarter;
            existingDay.Season = season;
            existingDay.Period = period;
            existingDay.WeekOfPeriod = weekOfPeriod;
            existingDay.WeekOfYear = weekOfYear;
            existingDay.DayOfYear = dayOfYear;
            existingDay.Date = date;
        }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cal = new Calendar();
        
        var row = cal.Select(c => c.Date).Where(d => d == "Fill Date for Comparison");
    }
}
```

**Important Modifications:**

1. Made `ICalendar<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>`, to ensure that Linq call works
2. You can directly implement `IEnumerable<T>` until and unless something special is achieved by `ICalendar<T>`
3. We implement `GetEnumerator()` methods to make code compile
4. Now in class `Test` we make a call and `Select` results in `IEnumerable<CalendarDay>`, on which `Where` is used to fetch `Date` and compare with Request Date

**Other Important Points**

5. You shall provide code, which is simple / compilable and is just focussing on main problem statement, here I have to work on making your code compile.
6. `SelectMany` is Collection flattening, `Select` is simple Collection selection, you shall provide code which directly works on it without any additional requirement
7. All Linq methods are extension methods, you shall look into their definition from [.Net Reference Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/), which will help in better code usage